# How to convert BasicDBList to List<T> using MappingMongoConverter (spring-data-mongo)?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Executing below code returns the result that contains the element of type hashmap instead of type T (the basicDBList coming from mongoDB does not have "_class" attribute:

```
com.mongodb.BasicDBList basicDBList = // output of mongoDB query;

List<T> result = mongoOperations.getConverter().read(List.class, basicDbList);
```

Is there any way to provide type information of List to the read method ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you acquired your `BasicDBList` by calling the `getRawResults().get("result")` of an `AggregationResults` instance, you can instead call `getMappedResults`:

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(...);
AggregationResults<Foo> r = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "foos", Foo.class);
List<Foo> foos = r.getMappedResults();
```